# how do I keep the whole message in the same array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, youtube-api

I am using youtube's API and what I'm trying to achieve is to store comments in arrays so these comments can pop up at a specific time along with the video playing.

I have a solution but I want it to be easier to work with.

First off, I get the comments from the database along with when they're supposed to pop up and store these in their own arrays(bad things here is that I generate js arrays with php).

```
<?PHP

if(isset($_GET['video'])&& is_numeric($_GET['video'])){
    $idgr = $_GET['video'];
}

$querystring="select at_lenght from comments where Video_ID = '".$idgr."';";
$innerresult=mysql_query($querystring);

echo "message = [";
while ($innerrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($innerresult)) {
    echo "'".$innerrow['at_lenght']."',";
}
echo "];";

$querystring="select likes from comments where Video_ID = '".$idgr."';";
$innerresult=mysql_query($querystring);
echo "likes = [";
while ($innerrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($innerresult)) {
    echo "'".$innerrow['likes']."',";
}
echo "];";
$querystring="select text from comments where Video_ID = '".$idgr."';";
$innerresult=mysql_query($querystring);
echo "text = [";
while ($innerrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($innerresult)) {
    echo "'".$innerrow['text']."',";
}
echo "];";  ?>
```

Then I have a part of my youtube API code that is going to at every second search through the array that contains the start-time of each comment, if they match, the message should pop up:

```
var currenttime=0;
  function checkstop() {
      if(done == true ){
        playingup = setTimeout(checkstop, 1000);

        currenttime =  player.getCurrentTime(); //youtube current time

        for(var u = 0;u < message.length;u++){ //loops through all

                if (Math.round(currenttime) == message[u]) {
                    var messsss = text[u];
                    var likes = likes[u];
                    fadethis(messsss,likes); 
                }           
            }               
         }
      }
```

The bad thing is that I have to use so many separate arrays for all properties of a message and fetch for each array seperatly to create a message. 
Can I somehow store every data in the same array and if so, easily fetch this information?

Comment: anyone? would really help my project